# Adding WIT Rules in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops

I have been attempting to find a solution to edit the XML files of the WIT in VSTS so that I can customize it to add a rule on the Due Date field to be edited by the Supervisor only. However it seems that I am limited only to custom rules.

Are there any ways to do this aside from editing the XML file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not edit VSTS XML file.

You can also refer [Import and export process configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/witadmin/witadmin-import-export-process-configuration?toc=/vsts/work/customize/toc.json&bc=/vsts/work/customize/breadcrumb/toc.json):

> With witadmin, you can modify XML definition files to support the
>   On-premises XML process model. For Hosted XML and Inheritance process
>   models, you can only use witadmin commands to list information.

That means, you can export and import XML for TFS, but only can export XML for VSTS.

Comment: With this limitation is there any workaround to add custom rule to a work item field? Like only supervisors can edit Due Date on a work item.

Comment: What's the process template and the work item type do you wish to add the rule?

Comment: Scrum is the process template and we would like to customise the Due Date on the Product Backlog Work Item.

Comment: But as you can find in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/guidance/work-item-field#alphabetical-index, the Due Date field only used by Agile process (Issue type). And if you are using system process, there is no way to add customer rules.

Comment: We created a customer process based in Scrum template through inheritance. I had the option to customise the PBI form to show/hide fields.

Comment: I can confirm that even if I make an inherited process from the Agile process template I still cannot customize the Due Date field.

Comment: Is only available for inherited Agile process **Issue** WIT (not User Store or others) https://imgur.com/a/7vYkk. But for your situation, it can not be specified and rule unfortunately.